# Can't Detect wlan0 (Debian 8.6.0 Jessie)

Tags: debian, wifi

So I just recently installed Debian 8.6.0 Jessie and I've been having issues with wireless connection. My device can't detect wlan0 and I'm not really sure what to do about this.

When I do ifconfig -a it only shows eth0 and lo

then when i do
iwconfig

```
    lo        no wireless extensions.

    eth0     no wireless extensions.
```

Sorry for the lack of information on here, I'm fairly new to using Debian and linux in general so I'm not sure what else i can put to show more info about this.

(EDIT)
i did ip link show and all i got for the output was

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 20:25:64:c9:50:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I also have the following info about the hardware I'm using on [here](http://pastebin.com/ZVBvwsgX) (note: I am using a Toshiba Satellite S55 Series Laptop if that helps)

I also did dmesg and as I looked through  it i saw that there were errors in it (I'll paste the notable ones I've seen)

```
    [   10.817152] rtl8188ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
    [   10.841926] rtl8188ee 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin (-2)
    [   10.841927] rtl8188ee 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load failed w
```

Comment: What wifi hardware do you use? PCI -> output of `lspci`, USB -> output of `lsusb`. Does `dmesg` show anything suspicious after booting wrt. to the WLAN device? (In doubt, put the completely output in a pastebin etc. and give a link).

Comment: Try `ip link show` and make sure the device is available. If so, then check its `state`, as it may be `DOWN`.

Comment: I second dirkt. You need to determine exactly what WIFI hardware your computer has. Given that the rtl8188ee driver attempted to do something, you may have a Realtek device. If that's so, do as andreastsh suggested to install the firmware (it's not installed by default). See https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using a Toshiba Satellite too, and I'm a Debian user.

When I installed it I had to download the necessary drivers for my hardware.

First edit your file [/etc/sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) to include the `non-free` component. An example of `/etc/sources.list` is:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

Then you have to run:

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

This [package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-realtek) contains the driver `rtl8188efw.bin` which as you can see from your `dmesg` error messages it fails to load on boot.